# How can I implement Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(); in the crosshair script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hell! I have a problem with my crosshair script, i want to implement Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(); in it, so my crosshair will be able only to move where the camera is. But i can't figure out how it works, and how i can make that. ( I understand that i need to use it in the position = part. but it not works, and the documentation and explanations that I found in the internet, are very difficult to understand for me, because English isn't my first language ) Thank you.

The code:

```
    public Transform anchor;
public float maxMoveRadius;
public float sensitivity = 1f;

Vector3 position = Vector2.zero;

void Start () {

}

void Update () {

    Vector3 moveDelta = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"), 0);
    position = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(position + moveDelta * sensitivity, maxMoveRadius);

    transform.position = anchor.position + position; 
}
```

}

Comment: I believe it uses a `Raycast`.

Comment: Yes, it use Raycast.

Comment: Ok, so, if you want to do what it does, why does your code not include a raycast?